# How to enable sorting and filtering while the Excel is locked when creating Excel document using R?

Tags: r, excel, apache-poi, rjava, r-xlsx

I am trying to create an Excel spreadsheet using the XLSX package in R.
I need to protect some part of the a sheet, but still be able to do sorting or filtering for the main part.

To do this in excel, you have to set the cells of main part to be unlocked first, then enable sort and autofilter, and finally protect the sheet.

But in the XLSX package, it seems like there is no such functionality to enable sort or autofilter, or even simplely protect the sheet. 
I traced problem down to rjave, and then Apache POI.

In the [XSSFSheet class](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html), I can find the lockSort, lockAutoFilter, and protectSheet methods over there. And thanks to stackoverflow, i found out that

```
#sheet is the sheet object name. 
rJava::.jcall(sheet, "V", "protectSheet", "password")
```

can protect the sheet.

But I was unable to enable Sort or autofilter .

I tried:

```
rJava::.jcall(sheet, "V", "lockSort", FALSE)

rJava::.jcall(sheet, "V", "lockSort", "false")
```

both doesn't work.

Comment: You might find this helpful: `XLConnect` https://miraisolutions.wordpress.com/page/2/

Comment: I have read the manual of the XLConnect packge, and can't find any function related to my answer. Could you please figure it out directly?

Comment: Thanks to Simon Urbanek, what kindly answered my question at the rJava mailing list. The first code with FALSE is the right way to pass parameter. But the current implementation of the lockSort function under POI project does not accept any parameter which is contradict to the documentation. So there is no way to enable sorting or filtering while the Excel sheet is protected under R.